# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column. But that's not a column

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I seem to be getting a rather odd error. And, for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. But on a piece of SQLite code, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    populateTables()
  File "test.py", line 20, in populateTables
    curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE ISRC = " + line[8])
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: USTCZ0993316
```

The odd part is that USTCZ0993316 is a piece of data that I want to compare to. I don't know why it seems to think it is a column. Here is a much small version that gives the same issue.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

def tableSetup(name):
    if(name=="tracks"):
        curs.execute("CREATE TABLE tracks(id INT UNIQUE, name TINYTEXT, album_id INT, client_id INT, acr_record_num INT, ISRC TINYTEXT UNIQUE, track_length TINYTEXT, client_share FLOAT)")

def populateTables():
    tracks_csv=csv.reader(open('tables/tracks.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=";", quotechar='"')
    tracks_csv.next()
    for line in tracks_csv:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id = " + line[0])
        if not curs.fetchall():
            if "\"" in line[1]:
                line[1]=line[1].replace("\"","'")
            curs.execute("INSERT INTO tracks VALUES("+line[0]+",\""+line[1]+"\","+line[2]+","+line[3]+","+line[4]+",\""+line[5]+"\",\""+line[7]+"\","+line[12]+")")
    override_csv=csv.reader(open('tables/artist_override.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    override_csv.next()
    for line in override_csv:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE ISRC = " + line[8])
        print curs.fetchone()

#Set required Table Names
tables = ["tracks"]
testOut=open('tables/testOut.txt','w')
conn = sqlite3.connect('tables/test.db')

curs = conn.cursor()

# Create table if they don't already exist
curs.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
tableResults = curs.fetchall()
print
for table in tables:
    if not any(table == result[0] for result in tableResults):
        tableSetup(table)

populateTables()
conn.commit()
curs.close()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it doesn't have quotes then it's a column or a number.

```
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE ISRC = ?", (line[8],))
```

[Edit: "%s" isn't proper syntax. It should be "?". Also, if you're going to be condescending, at least be right about it.]

Comment: Unless it's a number I guess.
So I should also change the other Select line to:
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id = %d",(line[0],))
And the INSERT line to:
curs.execute("INSERT INTO tracks VALUES(%d,%s,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%d)",(line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5],line[7],line[12]))

Comment: `%d` is not a valid placeholder.

Comment: a) Don't be so condescending.
b) It should curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE ISRC = ?", (line[8],))